# Javascript: Mouseover thumbnail to view large image - Multiple instances

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a javascript option that will allow me to **mouseover a thumbnail image to replace the "large" image**.  The trick here is using the anchor href from the thumbnail link as the large image source.  I need this to work for multiple instances.

The `<img src="large1.jpg">` etc. can be removed if that helps

Below is a simplified version of the HTML code I am using.  This code cannot be changed.

Every id and class can be unique.

```
<div class="image-1">
    <img src="large1.jpg">
</div>


<div id="thumbs">
    <a id="thumb_1" href="large1.jpg" title="1"><img src="small1.jpg" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a id="thumb_2" href="large2.jpg" title="2"><img src="small2.jpg" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a id="thumb_3" href="large3.jpg" title="3"><img src="small3.jpg" alt="image 1"/></a>
</div>

... 

<div class="image-2">
    <img src="large2.jpg">
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
    <a id="thumb_1" href="another_large1.jpg" title="1"><img src="anout_small1.jpg" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a id="thumb_2" href="another_large2.jpg" title="2"><img src="another_small2.jpg" alt="image 1"/></a>
    <a id="thumb_3" href="another_large3.jpg" title="3"><img src="another_small3.jpg" alt="image 1"/></a>
</div>

...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, it is agreed here that [you shouldn't use greetings or salutations in your posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276033/pointless-question-edit/276037#276037). They get in the way of us readers figuring out the actual question. I've edited them out for you this time.

Comment: So you want the images to become bigger when you mouse over them.  Is that all, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this solution
    http://jsfiddle.net/dtdaynjp/

add to all "large" image unique class, image-1, image-2, image-3..

for each thumbs link add class similar like appropriate large image: thumb-image-1, thumb-image-2, thumb-image-1...

add this jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

    $(".mouseover a").mouseover(function(){
        var src=$(this).attr('href');
        var classs=$(this).attr('class');
        classs=classs.substr(6);        
        $('.'+classs).find('img').attr('src',src);

    })

})
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the CSS `:hover` selector.  Then you can add animations and other cool things to your images.

### [EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vrajsuyz/1/).

Comment: This is a good idea, but I'm looking to replace the large image vs. expanding the thumbnail where it is.